# adding alexa skill session attributes from nodejs

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

using session attributes in alexa skill in nodejs code

[image: code]

But getting output undefined. Undefined should be a fashion.

[image: undefined should be fashion].

Please refer to images for the code

```
    'expenseIntent': function () {
    var updatedIntent=this.event.request.intent;
    var category1 = this.event.request.intent.slots.category.value;
    var expense;
    if(category1=='fashion'){
        expense = '1000';
    }else if(category1=='travel'){

        expense = '2000';
    }else if(category1=='food'){

        expense = '3000';
    }else {

        expense = '4000';
    }
    this.attributes.lastSpeech = this.event.request.intent.slots.category.value;
    console.log(this.attributes);
    if (this.event.request.dialogState === "STARTED") {
    this.emit(":delegate", updatedIntent);
    }else if(this.event.request.dialogState !== "COMPLETED"){
    this.emit(":delegate", updatedIntent);
    }else {
    console.log("this.event.request.intent.slots.category.value"+this.event.request.intent.slots.category.value);
    this.response.speak("Amount spent on "+category1+" is " + expense);
    this.emit(':responseReady'); 
}
},
'intentTwo': function () {
    var a = this.attributes.lastSpeech;

    //var aa = this.event.request.intent.slots.categories.value;
    this.response.speak("you query was about " + a);
    this.emit(':responseReady');
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

For adding attributes to Session,

```
Object.assign(this.attributes, {
    "lastSpeech" = this.event.request.intent.slots.category.value;
});
```

For retrieving it from Session,

```
var a = this.attributes.lastSpeech;
```

Hope this helps you. All the best :)

Answer (score 0):

```
'expenseIntent': function () {
    var updatedIntent=this.event.request.intent;
    var category1 = this.event.request.intent.slots.category.value;
    var expense;
    if(category1=='fashion'){
        expense = '1000';
    }else if(category1=='travel'){

        expense = '2000';
    }else if(category1=='food'){

        expense = '3000';
    }else {

        expense = '4000';
    }
    this.attributes.lastSpeech = this.event.request.intent.slots.category.value;
    console.log(this.attributes);
    if (this.event.request.dialogState === "STARTED") {
    this.emit(":delegate", updatedIntent);
    }else if(this.event.request.dialogState !== "COMPLETED"){
    this.emit(":delegate", updatedIntent);
    }else {
    console.log("this.event.request.intent.slots.category.value"+this.event.request.intent.slots.category.value);
    this.response.speak("Amount spent on "+category1+" is " + expense);
    this.emit(':responseReady'); 
}
},
'intentTwo': function () {
    var a = this.attributes.lastSpeech;

    //var aa = this.event.request.intent.slots.categories.value;
    this.response.speak("you query was about " + a);
    this.emit(':responseReady');
},
```